# js canvas firing useless laser

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, html5-canvas

I hope you're doing well. I'm new to JavaScript and working on making a game. A ship shoots at alien spacecrafts, but there's a snag. There destroy function works perfectly except for when it doesn't. If I fire my arsenal of lasers, the ships miraculously survive the barrage until struck by the last laser. I need help triggering the destroy function when the alien crafts touch any laser. Below is the relevant code (I think) and there's a link to jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/235mX/

```
function drawLaser(){
laserList.forEach(function(Laser){
                Laser.y = Laser.y - 1;
                Ly = Laser.y;
                Lx = Laser.x;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = Laser.color;
                ctx.arc(Laser.x, Laser.y, 10, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
                ctx.arc(Laser.x, Laser.y + 10, 10, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
            });
        }


                                if(Lx >= Ax - 30 && Lx < Ax + 30 && Ly < Ay + 30 && Ly > Ay + 10){
                    destroyX = Lx;
                    destroyY = Ly;
                    enemy1 = 0;
                    destroy();

                }
                if(Lx >= Ax + 100 - 30 && Lx < Ax + 100 + 30 && Ly < Ay + 30 && Ly > Ay + 10){
                    destroyX = Lx;
                    destroyY = Ly;
                    enemy2 = 0;
                    destroy();

                }
                if(Lx >= Ax + 200 - 30 && Lx < Ax + 200 + 30 && Ly < Ay + 30 && Ly > Ay + 10){
                    destroyX = Lx;
                    destroyY = Ly;
                    enemy3 = 0;
                    destroy();

                }
                if(Lx >= Ax + 300 - 30 && Lx < Ax + 300 + 30 && Ly < Ay + 30 && Ly > Ay + 10){
                    destroyX = Lx;
                    destroyY = Ly;
                    enemy4 = 0;
                    destroy();
                }
```

Comment: The jsfiddle doesn't seem to work for me. a, d and spacebar don't seem to be doing anything. I am using Firefox Stable on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your collision detection doesn't check every enemy with collision with every laser. It only checks them against the last laser by checking the global variables `Lx` and `Ly`. To fix the problem, you need to wrap your collision-detection code into another `laserList.forEach(function(Laser){` so each enemies position gets compared to the position of every laser.

You could have found that error earlier when you wouldn't use global variables. You can define a variable in local scope by prefixing it with the keyword `var`. I would recommend you to [use strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) which disables implicit variable creation.